# How to prevent from calling async function many times but call completion for each of them?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

This is code I am using currently:

```
typealias ResponseHandler = (SomeResponse?, Error?) -> Void

class LoginService {
    private var authorizeTokenCompletions = [ResponseHandler]()
    func authorizeToken(withRefreshToken refreshToken: String, completion: @escaping ResponseHandler) {
        if authorizeTokenCompletions.isEmpty {
            authorizeTokenCompletions.append(completion)
            post { [weak self] response, error in
                self?.authorizeTokenCompletions.forEach { $0(response, error) }
                self?.authorizeTokenCompletions.removeAll()
            }
        } else {
            authorizeTokenCompletions.append(completion)
        }
    }

    private func post(completion: @escaping ResponseHandler) {
        // async
        completion(nil, nil)
    }
}
```

What is idea of above code?

1. authorizeToken function may be called as many times as it needs (for example 20 times)
2. Only one asynchronous request (post) may be pushed at a time.
3. All completions from called authorizeToken functions should be called with the same parameters as the first one completed.

Usage:

```
let service = LoginService()

service.authorizeToken(withRefreshToken: "") { a, b in print(a)}
service.authorizeToken(withRefreshToken: "") { a, b in print(a)}
service.authorizeToken(withRefreshToken: "") { a, b in print(a)}
service.authorizeToken(withRefreshToken: "") { a, b in print(a)}
service.authorizeToken(withRefreshToken: "") { a, b in print(a)}
```

All completions above should be printed with result from the first one which was called.

Is it possible to do this with RxSwift?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, as every time we trigger the function it gets dispatched and we can't access the callbacks from other threads. why not  the push the data to a singleton rather than calling it multiple times?

Comment: Your current code has obvious race conditions, unsafe multithreaded array manipulation and doesn't prevent `post` from being called multiple times, but you probably know all that. While there is probably a way to do what you want with rx-swift you could probably just make your completion handler array updates thread safe and use a dispatch semaphore to see if the post is already running.

Comment: @Paulw11 exactly i was just wirting that in an answer, however isn't preventing post from running again is what he doesn't want to do ?

Comment: No, point 2 in the requirements is that only one instance of `post` runs at any time.

Comment: @Paulw11 oh I missed that, yes you're right. but how's that going to help with calling back with the first `post` results, could you add an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with RxSwift?

Yes it is possible. [RxSwift and Handling Invalid Tokens.](https://danielt1263.medium.com/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29)

The simplest solution:

```
func authorizeToken(withRefreshToken refreshToken: String) -> Observable<SomeResponse> {
    Observable.create { observer in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            print("async operation")
            observer.onNext(SomeResponse())
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

let response = authorizeToken(withRefreshToken: "")
    .share(replay: 1)

response.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
response.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
response.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
response.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
response.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
```

The above will only work if all requests (`subscribe`s) are made before the first one completes. Just like your code.

If you want to store the response for use even after completion, then you can use `replay` instead of `share`.

```
let response = authorizeToken(withRefreshToken: "")
    .replayAll()

let disposable = response.connect() // this calls the async function. The result will be stored until `disposable.dispose()` is called.

response.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    response.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) }) // this won't perform the async operation again even if the operation completed some time ago.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering

> is it possible to do this with RxSwift

that's not possible, as every time we trigger the function it gets dispatched and we can't access the callbacks from other threads.

You're creating a race condition, a workaround is to populate the data once in a singleton, and rather than calling the function multiple times use that singleton.

some other approach might also work singleton is just an example.

> Race condition: A race condition is what happens when the expected completion order of a sequence of operations becomes unpredictable, causing our program logic to end up in an undefined state

Comment: order of calling completions doesnt matter for me… so it may not be race condition.

Comment: yes but you're trying to access ongoing tasks and modify them based on the first callback result, I don't think that's possible even with a semaphore to push one post at a time.

Comment: ok, so current solution is best possible;) Thank you

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Paulw11 could have another workaround, but currently yes my guesses are this is probably it.